# Stop JavaScript code running when C# validation failed

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server

I am trying to stop the JavaScript code to run when the data is found in the table (`dt.Rows.Count > 0`). At the moment the code is not inserting data in the database (that what I want) but the JavaScript continues running because I am still getting the successful insert message. Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<input type="button"  id="btnAddConsent" value="Add Consent"   onclick="insertData();" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function insertData() {
    var MBID = document.getElementById("txtConsentMBID").value;
    var ConsentID = document.getElementById("DropDownListConsent").value;
    var ConsentDate = document.getElementById("txtPatientConsentDate").value;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "insertConsent.aspx?mb=" + MBID + " &ci= " + ConsentID + "&cd=" + ConsentDate, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    ConsentID = document.getElementById("DropDownListConsent").value = "";
    ConsentDate = document.getElementById("txtPatientConsentDate").value = "";
    alert("Consent Added Successfully");
}
```

**C#**

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString))
{
    MBID = Request.QueryString["mb"].ToString();
    ConsentID = Request.QueryString["ci"].ToString();
    ConsentDate = Request.QueryString["cd"].ToString();

    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@" select * from ConsentGroup where ConsentID = @ConsentID and MBID=@MBID ", con))
    {
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MBID", MBID);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConsentID", ConsentID);
        //sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConsentDate", ConsentDate);
        //sc.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sc);
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // this message should displayed when count is more that 1
            Response.Write("alert('This Patient already has this Concent saved in the Database');");
        }
        else
        {
            using (SqlCommand sc1 = new SqlCommand(@"insert into ConsentGroup (MBID, ConsentID, ConsentDate, ConsentWithdraw, ConsentConfirm) 

            values('" + MBID + "','" + ConsentID + "','" + ConsentDate + "','NO','YES')", con))
            {
                sc1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Ack...your first query you parameterized but your insert statement is wide open to sql injection. Why did you change? You need to parameterize ALL your queries. And you might take a peek at this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` has an event listener `onreadystatechange` which is called as the http request is progressing. When `readyState` is 4, the request is complete. At this point, you may intercept what is returned from your function, and determine which alert should be shown.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
    {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help